# How to get O(1) time complexity for Array.remove(at:) in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, time-complexity

I know usually it takes O(n) time to remove an item from a Swift Array by using `remove(at:)`.

Let us say I have some code like this:

```swift
// refArray has m elements
// myArray has n elements

for refItem in refArray {
    for (index, item) in myArray.enumerated() {
        if item.id == refItem.id {
            <Do something>
            myArray.remove(at: index)
            break
        }
    }
}
```

for `myArray.remove(at: index)`, even I already know the index of the item to be deleted, but if I
use `remove(at:)`, it still takes O(n) time.
So the whole process could take O(n³) time.

Is there any way to make it O(n²) but still removing an item from `myArray` when `item.id == refItem.id`?

Comment: Can both arrays contain elements that have duplicate ids? If not, consider using sets.

Comment: Store all the required indices for deletion then do deletion in one go

Comment: Why don't you use `RangeReplaceableCollection` method `removeAll(where:)`  and use a predicate `Complexity: O(n)`? If there is only one element that matches the condition get the `firstIndex(where:)` and remove it.

Comment: Btw there is no way to make it O(1)

Comment: This whole process is already O(n^2), due to the `break`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `myArray` does not contain items with duplicate IDs, you can use `removeAll(where:)` instead of your double for loops:

```
myArray.removeAll(where: { item in 
    refArray.contains { $0.id == item.id }
})
```

This is O(n*m), where n and m are the size of `myArray` and `refArray` respectively.

Otherwise, you can do what starboy_b says in the comments, collect all the indices and remove them in one go with `remove(atOffsets:)`:

```
var indicesToRemove = IndexSet()
for refItem in refArray {
    for (index, item) in myArray.enumerated() {
        if i == j, !indicesToRemove.contains(index) {
            indicesToRemove.insert(index)
            break
        }
    }
}
myArray.remove(atOffsets: indicesToRemove)
```

This is also O(n*m).

Comment: I think a better approach would be to create 2 sets, get its intersection and use it to check if it contains when removing the elements. Still need to consider the fact that op is mentioning that he needs to do some operation prior to removal.

Comment: refArray should definitely be converted to a set IMO where contains is O(1)

Comment: @LeoDabus That's making quite a lot of assumptions isn't it? For that to work, whatever is in those arrays needs to conform to `Hashable` using only `id` (which does not necessarily make sense), and `myArray` needs to contain no elements with duplicate IDs (otherwise you are changing the behaviour of OP's original code).

Comment: Yes I agree OP should have given more details about the real problem

Answer (score 4):

If you want to remove *m* items from an array of *n* items, yes, you could refactor that to achieve O(m*n) time complexity. But whenever you see nested `for` loops (or nested functions that are tantamount to the same thing), you should consider whether there are structures you could build that will cut that O(m*n) down to O(m+n), which is dramatically faster.

In this case, we do have such an opportunity. So, we first build a hashed structure of the values for which we will be searching. Then we can iterate through the array once looking for records to be removed, each with O(1) complexity. And as discussed elsewhere, rather than having your own `for` loop calling `remove(at:)`, we can employ methods like [`removeAll(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/rangereplaceablecollection/3018274-removeall) will do this looping and removing all in one step of O(n) complexity.

```swift
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    mutating func remove(values: [Element]) {
        let set = Set(values)
        removeAll { set.contains($0) }
    }
}
```

And then

```swift
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
var values = [1, 3, 5]
array.remove(values: values)
print(array)                       // [0, 2, 4, 6]
```

There are lots of variations on the theme, but the idea is generally the same: If you can, build a structure where values to be removed can be identified in O(1) time. Then you can iterate through the array only once, e.g. using `removeAll`. Then net result is an overall O(m+n) time complexity, which is far faster than either your original algorithm or the contemplated O(m*n) rendition.

Note, patterns like this work if (a) the elements in the array are `Hashable`; and (b) we are OK increasing the space complexity of the algorithm. We are, in short, sacrificing space complexity for improvements in the time complexity.

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant in my comment on Sweeper's answer. I would just extend `RangeReplaceableCollection` instead of Array and pass the method to the method instead of using a closure `extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Hashable {` `mutating func remove(values: [Element]) {` `removeAll(where: Set(values).contains)` `}`
`}`

Comment: Like I said, there are lots of ways to skin the cat. I was focusing on the big picture, avoiding nested `for` loops, and using some structure that allows O(1) lookup performance.

Comment: Sure this does answer the question. I was just trying to add value to your post. I have already voted it up as well.

Comment: For giggles and grins, I benchmarked both our approaches, and the performance was indistinguishable (though, unsurprisingly, several orders of magnitude better than the O(m*n) approach).

Comment: The the main advantage of extending `RangeReplaceableCollection` is to support `String` as well but I forgot to make the method generic `mutating func remove<S: Sequence>(values: S) where S.Element == Element {`

Answer (score 0):

If order isn't important, you can use swapAt(indexOfElementToRemove, lastIndex) and then removeLast(). This achieves O(1) time. However, a Set may be a better type to use.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).